# Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be availabe in this workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Having an issue with VBA error 'run time 1004'. Using the following code. The macro is called from a button in Row 5, hence the subtraction. There are other buttons in rows 6, 7, 8 etc. all calling the same macro (to subsequently call a specific userform), hence the variable.

```
Sub Export()
    i = RowNumber - 4

    Reinstated = "ReinstateR" & i

    Application.Run Reinstated

End Sub
```

The macros 'ReinstateR1', 'ReinstateR2' etc. are all stored in a separate module.

```
Sub ReinstateR1()

'Macro function etc.

End Sub
```

For some reason, though, when I click the button, I get the following error message:

"Cannot run the macro 'ReinstateR1'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

All macros are enabled, the macro is in the same workbook, etc. Trust centre settings are set to disable all macros with notification, etc.

I'm stumped. I can call the macro without the variable, but that's not the point...

Comment: What is the name of the module that the macros are in?

Comment: The Export macro is in a module called 'Exporter', whilst the ReinstateR# macros are in a module called 'Reinstater1'.

Comment: There's your problem. Trying to run Reinstater1 will fail because the module and routine have the same name. You either need to add the module name: `Application.Run "Renstater1." & Reinstated` or, preferably, give the module a different name to the routines.

Comment: That never crossed my mind, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Rory That should be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a module with the same name as a routine it contains, you need to prefix any call to it using `Application.Run` with the module name as well (or change the name of either the module or the routine), so in this case it's:

```
Application.Run "Reinstater1." & Reinstated
```